# How can I access my classe's var inside the class?

Tags: php

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a = 'blablabla';
}
```

And I want to access the variable `$a` inside the class without needing to use any function, like

```
class MyClass {
    public $a = 'blablabla';
    public $b = $a;
}
```

I tried using `public $b = $this->a`, `public $b = MyClass->a`, and many other alternative ways to try to do what I want, and nothing. And I didn't find anything on Google that could explain what I want.

Could someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: public $b = self::$a;

Comment: Why would you need to assign another variable to your variable? 
Cant you use directly `$a`?

Comment: You could set `$this->b = $this->a` on the `__construct()`

Comment: because I'm using `get_class_vars()` function and I need to repeat some variables

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why a simple variable call will not work, but you can try:

```
 class MyClass {
  public $a = 'blablabla';

   function geta(){
   return $this->a;
    }
   $b=geta();
}
```

Comment: because `$a` in a class is a local variable, like any other variable anywhere else in php. `$this->a` explicitly refers to a class attribute.

Comment: It should be `return $this->a;`, without second dollar sign.